# My task in task scheduler is executing my batch twice for no apparent reason

Tags: batch-file, task, windows-task-scheduler

- I created two batch files to synchronize data **TO** and
  **FROM** Google Drive
- One batch file executes when the application launches and one batch
  file executes when the application closes
- The task scheduled to execute the initial batch is actually executing
  twice. Once when the executable launches and again when the
  executable closes. I don't know why.
- The contents of my custom event filters are posted at the bottom of this post.

Background:

The application is actually a legacy game with no cloud save feature. I'm using Google drive as a workaround. The game actually has **two separate executables**. One is the initial launcher that gives the player the option to choose single player and other options. The second exe is the actual campaign.

I setup two tasks in taskscheduler that engages two separate batch files. They function to sync game save data to and from google drive. The first task launches the initial batch file which will sync data from Google Drive. The second batch file synchronizes game data to google drive when single player is closed.

I discovered the issue when I attempted a simple A-B test. After manually moving game save data into a google drive folder, I deleted the contents of the local game save folder and then launched the game. The first scheduled task functioned as expected. The game save folder was populated with save data.

While the game was running I used my second monitor to delete the contents of the google drive folder. Once I selected single player, I noticed that all the contents of the local game save folder disappeared.

I quickly realized that the initial batch file was run again upon exit of the game launcher. In my batch files, I'm using Windows' Robocopy mir command to pull and push data to a designated google drive folder.

If the initial batch file is run once again after the deletion of data inside the google drive folder, then it will also delete everything in the local game save folder (No worries, I backed up all the data to a third folder as a precaution). I obviously did NOT program taskscheduler to behave this way.

Here is what I entered into Task #1 via the custom event filter:

```
    <QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]]
 and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='D:\Installed Games\Splinter Cell Double Agent\SCDALauncher.exe')]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

I'm not having any issues (that I'm aware of) with Task #2, but here it is just in case you can find something:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]] and *[EventData[(Data='D:\Installed Games\Splinter Cell Double Agent\SCDA-Offline\System\SplinterCell4.exe')]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Below are the contents of my batch files:

**Batch file #1** (Syncs files FROM Google Drive)

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Penn\Google Drive\Game Saves\Tom Clancy's Splinter Cell Double Agent\Save" "C:\ProgramData\Ubisoft\SplinterCell4\Save" /MIR /MT
```

**Batch File #2** (Syncs files TO Google Drive)

```
robocopy "C:\ProgramData\Ubisoft\SplinterCell4\Save" "C:\Users\Penn\Google Drive\Game Saves\Tom Clancy's Splinter Cell Double Agent\Save" /MIR /MT
```

**Note***
I'm aware that this issue wouldn't necessarily have any impacts on my use-case scenario because there wouldn't ordinarily be any changes to save data between executing the launcher and single player campaign, but I would certainly want to make sure I can safely use a similar technique in other cases without unexpected behavior.

Comment: `I created two batch files ...` posting batch files code would help a lot. How we may know whatever issue in your code when such code is not visible?

Comment: Silly me. I've updated the OP with the requested information.

Comment: Please explain why you're delibetately adding trailing spaces to the ends of your directory names!

Comment: I suppose you're talking about the batch files. If I remember correctly, the first batch files I ever created didn't have any trailing spaces. I think at one point I would keep getting "command not recognized" error messages in command prompt. Adding trailing spaces fixed the issue for some reason and I've been adding them ever since because I always model my newer batch files after the older ones. It might've been something that only pertains to robocopy, but I'm not sure. All I know is that the batch files apparently work just fine and I don't believe they are the source of the issue.

Comment: Let me put it another way, remove the trailing spaces from your directories!

Comment: Point taken. I've removed all trailing spaces.